# What's the idiomatic way of parsing dynamic YAML in Go?

Tags: go, yaml

I have some code for handling a YAML config file that's getting a little out-of-control w/ type assertions and I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

Here's the relevant snippet from my config file:

```
plugins:
  taxii20:
    default: default
    api_roots:
      default:
        auth:
          - ldap
          - mutualtls
        collections:
          all:
            selector: g.V().Save("<type>").Save("<created>").All()
            selector_query_lang: gizmo
```

And here's my parsing code:

```
func parseTaxiiConfig() {
    plg.ConfigMutex.Lock()
    taxiiConfig := plg.ConfigData.Plugins["taxii20"].(map[interface{}]interface{})
    ConfigData = &Config{}
    if taxiiConfig["default"] != nil {
        ConfigData.DefaultRoot = taxiiConfig["default"].(string)
    }
    if taxiiConfig["api_roots"] != nil {
        ConfigData.APIRoots = make([]model.APIRoot, 0)
        iroots := taxiiConfig["api_roots"].(map[interface{}]interface{})
        for iname, iroot := range iroots {
            root := model.APIRoot{Name: iname.(string)}
            authMethods := iroot.(map[interface{}]interface{})["auth"].([]interface{})
            root.AuthMethods = make([]string, 0)
            for _, method := range authMethods {
                root.AuthMethods = append(root.AuthMethods, method.(string))
            }
            collections := iroot.(map[interface{}]interface{})["collections"].(map[interface{}]interface{})
            root.Collections = make([]model.Collection, 0)
            for icolName, icollection := range collections {
                collection := model.Collection{Name: icolName.(string)}
                collection.Selector = icollection.(map[interface{}]interface{})["selector"].(string)
                collection.SelectorQueryLang = icollection.(map[interface{}]interface{})["selector_query_lang"].(string)
                root.Collections = append(root.Collections, collection)
            }
            ConfigData.APIRoots = append(ConfigData.APIRoots, root)
        }
    }
    plg.ConfigMutex.Unlock()

    // debug
    fmt.Println(ConfigData)
}
```

The code works as intended, but there's just so many type assertions here and I can't shake the feeling that I'm missing a better way.

One possible critical item of note, as the config implies, this is configuration for a Caddy-style plugin system, so the main config parser cannot know ahead of time what the shape of the plugin config will look like. It has to delegate processing of the plugin's portion of the config file to the plugin itself.

Comment: Actually, found some of my coworker's code that's solving this problem with http://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure – I'll update this question shortly if I can get that to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with instead. Much more readable.

```
// Config represents TAXII 2.0 plugin structure
type Config struct {
    DefaultRoot string
    APIRoots    []model.APIRoot
}

// Intermediate config for mapstructure
type configRaw struct {
    DefaultRoot string                `mapstructure:"default"`
    APIRoots    map[string]apiRootRaw `mapstructure:"api_roots"`
}
type apiRootRaw struct {
    AuthMethods []string                 `mapstructure:"auth"`
    Collections map[string]collectionRaw `mapstructure:"collections"`
}
type collectionRaw struct {
    Selector          string `mapstructure:"selector"`
    SelectorQueryLang string `mapstructure:"selector_query_lang"`
}

func parseTaxiiConfig() error {
    plg.ConfigMutex.Lock()
    defer plg.ConfigMutex.Unlock()

    taxiiConfig := plg.ConfigData.Plugins["taxii20"].(map[interface{}]interface{})
    fmt.Println(taxiiConfig)
    ConfigData = &Config{}
    raw := &configRaw{}
    err := mapstructure.Decode(taxiiConfig, raw)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    ConfigData.DefaultRoot = raw.DefaultRoot
    ConfigData.APIRoots = make([]model.APIRoot, 0)
    for name, root := range raw.APIRoots {
        apiRoot := model.APIRoot{Name: name}
        apiRoot.AuthMethods = root.AuthMethods
        apiRoot.Collections = make([]model.Collection, 0)
        for colName, col := range root.Collections {
            collection := model.Collection{Name: colName}
            collection.Selector = col.Selector
            collection.SelectorQueryLang = col.SelectorQueryLang
            apiRoot.Collections = append(apiRoot.Collections, collection)
        }
        ConfigData.APIRoots = append(ConfigData.APIRoots, apiRoot)
    }

    return nil
}
```